# Выборка из двух таблиц SQL

Tags: sql, выборка

Добрый вечер, народ помогите пожалуйста. 
Есть таблица `Client` со столбцами `id_client`, `phone_client`, `name_client`, `taxipark_id_taxipark`. Есть таблица `Taxipark` со столбцами `id_taxipark`, `name_taxipark`, `phone_taxipark`. Есть Client "Максим". Нужно вывести таксопарк, обслуживающий "Максима". 
Запрос:

```
select name_taxipark 
from   taxipark 
where  id_taxipark in (select taxipark_id_taxipark 
                       from   client 
                       where  name_client.client = 'Maxim');
```

Вылетает:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'name_client.client' in 'where
>   clause'

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Comment: замените `name_client.client` на `client.name_client`. Сначала указывается имя таблицы, а потом ее поле

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select taxipark.name_taxipark
from   client, taxipark
where  client.name_client = 'Maxim' AND 
       client.taxipark_id_taxipark = taxipark.id_taxipark
```

вроде не запутался с вашими названиями...

---

А вообще, есть предложение сделать названия столбцов покороче. Никаких проблем (путаницы) в дальнейшем не будет. Но будет более читабельно... и всем привычнее...

```
taxiparks [id, name, phone]
clients   [id, name, phone, taxipark_id]
```

И запрос тогда будет выглядеть так

```
SELECT taxiparks.name
FROM   taxiparks, clients
WHERE  taxiparks.id = clients.taxipark_id AND
       clients.name = 'Maxim'
```

Исправление.

Лучше писать с inner join или, если нужно, с left join.

```
SELECT
    taxiparks.name
FROM
    clients
LEFT JOIN
    taxiparks ON clients.taxipark_id = taxiparks.id
WHERE
    clients.name = 'Maxim'
```

Comment: from   client, taxipark - вы тут вроде JOIN забыли, или без него тоже работает?

Comment: Работает и так, но, вы правы, лучше писать с джойнами. Может да же left join сделать.. все зависит от вашей схемы базы данных и потребностей. Добавлю вариант с left join в ответ.

Comment: @Виктор Оператор "запятая" в предложении FROM, большинства диалектов SQL равнозначен INNER JOIN, только условия объединения пишутся со всеми остальными в предложении WHERE.